# Call Secure ASP.Net API from Windows 8 Phone App with WebClient

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api, webclient

i cretaed my own windows phone app based on this touturial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/mobile-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application

So far everyting is working.

Now i secured my Controller with [Authentication].
When i call the API from a browser, i get redirected to a loginpage with forms Auth.

The same thing when i try to get the records from my phone app. Can anyone help me coding the webClient to the get all my data from the webapi with the Windows 8 Phone App?

```
Asp.net API Controller:
 public class AlertsController : ApiController
    {
        private AlertRepository repository = null;

        public AlertsController()
        {
            this.repository = new AlertRepository();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            IEnumerable<AlertDetails> alerts = this.repository.ReadAllAlerts();
            if (alerts != null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<AlertDetails>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, alerts);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
        }
enter code here



The WebClient in MainViewModel from the PhoneApp:

using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using AlertCatalog.Resources;
using System.Net;
using AlertCatalog.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace AlertCatalog.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        const string apiUrl = @"http://localhost:25518/api/Alerts";
            public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A collection for ItemViewModel objects.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

        public bool IsDataLoaded
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates and adds a few ItemViewModel objects into the Items collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        //Create an instance of your new CookieAware Web Client



public void LoadData()
        {
            if (this.IsDataLoaded == false)
            {
                this.Items.Clear();
                this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = "0", LineOne = "Please Wait...", LineTwo = "Please wait while the catalog is downloaded from the server.", LineThree = null });
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testusername", "testpassword");
                webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
                webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadCatalogCompleted);
                webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(apiUrl));
            }
        }

        private void webClient_DownloadCatalogCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Items.Clear();
                if (e.Result != null)
                {
                    var alerts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlertDetails[]>(e.Result);
                    int id = 0;
                    foreach (AlertDetails alert in alerts)
                    {
                        this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()
                        {
                            ID = (id++).ToString(),
                            LineOne = alert.Severity,
                            LineTwo = alert.Name,
                            LineThree = alert.Description.Replace("\n", " ")
                        });
                    }
                    this.IsDataLoaded = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel()
                {
                    ID = "0",
                    LineOne = "An Error Occurred",
                    LineTwo = String.Format("The following exception occured: {0}", ex.Message),
                    LineThree = String.Format("Additional inner exception information: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message)
                });
            }
        }
```

ErrorMessage:
[Error from PhoneApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtKNn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("testusername", "testpassword");` does not mean that your api will recognise the user as authorized.

You can derive from the `AuthorizeAttribute`to specify your own authorization rules.

e.g.

```
public class MyAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //Implement your own checks here
        //httpContext.Request.Headers["yourHeaderToCheck"]
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then replace `[Authorize]` with `[MyAuth]`